# Find package Eigen3 for CMake

Tags: cmake, eigen

CMake cannot find my **Eigen3** package. I set an environment variable called

```
EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR
```

pointing to the path where `FindEigen3.cmake` is.

Then in the CMakelists.txt I wrote:

```
find_package( Eigen3 REQUIRED )
include_directories( EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR )
```

I get next message of error:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:91 (MESSAGE):
  Could NOT find Eigen3 (missing: EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR EIGEN3_VERSION_OK)
  (Required is at least version "2.91.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:252 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindEigen3.cmake:76 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  test/test_quaternion/CMakeLists.txt:25 (find_package)
```

Any idea on what I am missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Since Eigen3 is completely header only, all you ever need is the path to the include directory. And this one, you are already defining manually anyway. So there is no real need for a `FindEigen3.cmake` or `FIND_PACKAGE` call.

Simply use

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ( "$ENV{EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}" )
```

or

```
SET( EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR "$ENV{EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}" )
IF( NOT EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR )
    MESSAGE( FATAL_ERROR "Please point the environment variable EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR to the include directory of your Eigen3 installation.")
ENDIF()
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ( "${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}" )
```

A few notes:

1. If you want to access the *content* of a CMake variable, make sure to use `${...}`
2. `$ENV{....}` accesses environment variables.
3. The second example will stop with an error if the environment variable is not set (and, thus, EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR cmake variable is empty)
4. Be careful to use quotation marks around (evaluated) variables if they could contain whitespace. Otherwise, CMake will interpret it as a list.
5. If you want to use custom find modules, make sure to either place them in you CMake installation or, as @Fraser pointed out above, make sure to point `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` to the directory where it is. Not sure, but it could be that CMake checks the current directory as well automatically (where your `CMakeLists.txt` resides. Anyhow, setting `EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR` is totally unrelated to the location of `FindEigen3.cmake`
6. However, it could be that your `FindEigen3` script *evaluates* this variable to determine the location of your Eigen3 installation.
7. Alternatively, self-built CMake-based projects often provide a `<PackageName>Config.cmake`. If you point a variable called `<PackageName>_DIR` to the directory containing this file, you can use `FIND_PACKAGE( <PackageName> ...)` as normal. See [documentation of FIND_PACKAGE](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:find_package) for details.

Comment: Yes, this the answer I was looking for. The key is the **$ENV**, thanks man. I learned a lot with this post.

Comment: Missing closing parenthesis after **MESSAGE( FATAL_ERROR "Please point the environment variable EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR to the include directory of your Eigen3 installation."**

Comment: What is the Eigen3 Include Directory?

Comment: How to set EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR?

Comment: If `EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR` is not defined in environment variables, the method will not work

Answer (score 29):

Eigen >= 3.3 has direct CMake integration, so it seems yours isn't set up correctly.

Assume Eigen has been installed to `/opt/eigen/3.3` with default settings. Append or prepend the the location `/opt/eigen/3.3` to the environment variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` e.g in bash:

```
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="$CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:/opt/eigen/3.3"
```

Then CMake should pick it up.

---

If you are writing your own CMakeLists.txt that uses Eigen I suggest using code like this:

```
find_package (Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED)
add_executable (example example.cpp)
target_link_libraries (example Eigen3::Eigen)
```

You *should not* use `include_directories` since CMake 3 was released -- the targets approach should be preferred whenever available.

Comment: That's the only answer here which is almost right... The only thing is that you need to prepend '/opt/eigen/3.3' to the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, and not a complete path to where cmake files are stored. This way you only need  a single prefix path for all libs installed to some fake root path.

Comment: @Slava I verified that this worked, and incorporated your feedback.

Comment: Can I ask why one should not use `include_directories` ? Isn't Eigen a header only library?

Comment: "Can I ask why one should not use include_directories ? Isn't Eigen a header only library?" It still has requirements such as C++11+ and may need to link to `libm` on certain platforms. However, I think you misunderstood the note about `include_directories` -- that changes global state, instead of a per-target state.

Answer (score 11):

First, make sure Eigen is properly installed. Refer to the `INSTALL` file that comes with the tarball.

Second, copy the `cmake/FindEigen3.cmake` file from the tarball to the directory containing your `CMakeLists.txt`.

In your `CMakeLists.txt` add:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

Now you should be able to do e.g. `#include <Eigen/Core>`.

All of this comes (mostly) from this [source](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=94166).

This approach has the advantage over e.g. `include_directories("$ENV{EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}")` that it the uses CMake's standard mechanism for finding external dependencies, making it easier for someone else (or your future self) to pick up the project, possibly on another platform.

(However, it would be nice if Eigen itself installed an EigenConfig.cmake file, making it accessible through the `find_package` mechanism without any extra paths.)

Comment: No, Eigen should install cmake config package files. http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-packages

Comment: It probably should, but it's not a full remedy. If Eigen wasn't installed, the error messages would be more cryptic, mostly revolving around CMake not being able to find the FindEigen3.cmake file itself. ...which might prompt you to include the file in your package anyway. Post edited.

Comment: You're mixing up concepts. According to the doc I linked to (and wrote), Eigen would install EigenConfig.cmake, not FindEigen.cmake.

Comment: @steveire: Yes, I was a bit sloppy with the concepts. Regarding the inclusion of an Eigen module in CMake, [this page](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:Module_Maintainers) makes it abundantly clear that CMake-based packages should provide their own package configuration files rather than a find module in CMake. Thanks for taking the time to get this right. Post edited.

Comment: Also, using the `CONFIG` option with `find_package` for CMake-based packages (with package configuration files) makes the error message a bit more concise when no package is found.

Answer (score 4):

I found another solution [here](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/issues/106) (which referred to [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/diff/eigen3.patch?h=ros-jade-pcl-ros&id=f7816993efa9ca68137cde7e35f7c1b61635ca4a)) which uses the pkg-config file :

```
find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_search_module(Eigen3 REQUIRED eigen3)
```

Answer (score 4):

As a detailed explanation of the **note 7** from the top answer of Johannes. By using the "Config mode" rather than "Module mode" of CMake find_packate(), only writing

```
find_package( Eigen3 REQUIRED )
include_directories( EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR )
```

in CMakeLists.txt is enough.

Please refer to the **INSTALL** guidance text file contained in the eigen source code directory (eg. extracted from eigen-3.3.7.tar.gz downloaded from [official website](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page#Download)), which said:

```
Method 2. Installing using CMake
********************************

Let's call this directory 'source_dir' (where this INSTALL file is).
Before starting, create another directory which we will call 'build_dir'.

Do:

  cd build_dir
  cmake source_dir   
  make install

The "make install" step may require administrator privileges.

You can adjust the installation destination (the "prefix")
by passing the -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=myprefix option to cmake, as is
explained in the message that cmake prints at the end.
```

Just like installing usual CMake projects to your machine.

The difference from directly including the **/usr/include/eigne3** or **/usr/local/include/eigen3** directory is that, a configuration directory called **eigen3/cmake** will also be installed to **/usr/share** or **usr/local/share**. This configuration directory contains the **Eigen3Config.cmake** file, which can automatically be found by CMake to locate the eigen3 directory.

Answer (score 3):

If you have not added Eigen Library to environment variable then do the following in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(ProjectName)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

# set EIGEN_DIR variable to Eigen Library Path
set(EIGEN_DIR "C:\\Eigendir\\Eigen")

# include the directory
include_directories(${EIGEN_DIR})

add_executable(ProjectName main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(ProjectName ${EIGEN_DIR})
```

Answer (score 2):

Another simple way that doesn't require adding an environment variable is to simply find eigen with the cmake find_path function https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/find_path.html. The example code finds the directory "Eigen" in paths "/usr/include/" and "/usr/local/include" with an additional search in subdirectory "eigen3".

```
find_path(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS "Eigen" paths "/usr/include" "/usr/local/include" path_suffixes "eigen3")
message(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
if ( NOT EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS )
    message(FATAL_ERROR "CMake variable EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS not found.")
endif()
include_directories ( "${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS}" )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` to the location of Eigen subdirectory named "cmake":

```
cmake . -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=<Eigen root dir>/cmake/
```

Comment: And how can I write this in the cmakelists, instead of as a command line?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when run `cmake .. && make` on Google Colab on a project clone from github. I fixed it by editing CMakeLists.txt file and adding this line to it:

```
set(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR "/usr/include/eigen3")
```

As you can see, my eigen3 was in /usr/include/eigen3 path (and I had installed it using `!sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake libeigen3-dev`)

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

- Changed `c++11` to `c++14`
- Changed `find_package(Eigen3 QUIET)` to `find_package(Eigen3 CONFIG)`

Answer (score 0):

When installing on Kubuntu 20.04 following steps from INSTALL:

Do:

cd build_dir
cmake source_dir
make install

using -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/eigen-3.4.0 and sudo
FindEigen3.cmake is not installed. However, using

set(Eigen3_DIR "/usr/local/eigen/share/eigen3/cmake")

seem to work. FindEigen3.cmake is in the build directory
but it is not copied to the installation directory tree.

Answer (score -1):

Another simple way is:

if the Eigen library is in /opt/eigen/3.3/Eigen

`include_directories(/opt/eigen/3.3)`

which is equivalent to what Jai suggested

```
set(EIGEN_DIR "/opt/eigen/3.3")
include_directories(${EIGEN_DIR})
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to read official documentation:

- Click [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCMakeGuide.html)
- After install Eigen from tar and compile it correctly.
- CMakeLists.txt will looks like this:

```
    find_package(Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} something.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Eigen3::Eigen)
```

It will be fine work.