# How to include in CMake the files on which Eigen depends?

Tags: include, cmake, eigen

I am working on a C project which I downloaded from the Internet.
I am trying to add some functions in which Eigen is to be used for linear algebra.

To that end, I added the following lines to the CMakeLists.txt :

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(EIGEN3 REQUIRED eigen3)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${EIGEN3_LIBRARY_DIRS})
ADD_EXECUTABLE(main main.c)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(main ${EIGEN3_LIBRARIES})
```

and I get no errors when running cmake . and then make

The issue is when I try to include `<Eigen/Dense>` in one of the c functions, I get the following error when I try to make:

```
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:28:19: fatal error: complex: No such file or directory  #include <complex>
```

`Eigen/Dense` includes `Eigen/Core` and `Eigen/Core` includes `<complex>`
I think it's just not looking in the correct directory to find `complex`... How to make it look there?

Comment: Check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249140/find-package-eigen3-for-cmake/12258855#12258855) to learn how to search for Eigen in CMake. (But @jet47 is right in regard to your project being C, not C++)

Comment: Thanks for your advice :)
I tried what you mentioned in the other post but it doesn't solve the problem. The include directories of Eigen are already there and as I mentioned `cmake .` is not returning any error. What is missing though is including C++ standard libraries like `/usr/include/c++/4.8/` for example, which do not get automatically included since the project is a C project, as @jet47 pointed.
Should I try to add those manually, or how should I proceed to use Eigen in this C project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eigen is a C++ library, while your application source is a C file (`main.c`). Since it has a `.c` extension, CMake treats it as C source and uses the C compiler, which doesn't know about the C++ standard library (`<complex>`). Rename `main.c` to `main.cpp`.

Comment: Oh, now I see! Thanks for your reply.

The whole project is written in C not in C++, I wasn't careful when I explained my situation.

So changing main.c to main.cpp is not the right way to do it I guess...

Do you know whether Eigen can be used for a C project?
If yes, how to solve the include issues?

Comment: As far as I know, Eigen is C++ library and can't be used in C project. But you can move all code that use Eigen to separate file and compile the file as C++, and leave the rest part of the project as C.

Comment: Exactly, I think that's what I should do if I decide to stick to Eigen
Many Thanks :)