# None of the required 'eigen3' found

Tags: cmake, eigen3

Trying to install deepdetect by following the installation steps [here](https://deepdetect.com/overview/installing/)
I have eigen installed correctly at /usr/include/eigen3
I am trying to build from source but when I use

```
cmake ..
```

I get this error

```
Checking for one of the modules 'eigen3'
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:578 
(message):
None of the required 'eigen3' found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:52 (pkg_search_module)
```

Can someone please help me fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might help if you give more information, e.g., what OS are you on. Have you checked the issues at deepdetect? This seems to be related: https://github.com/beniz/deepdetect/issues/279

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04. I've applied the fixes in your repo but nothing seems to work for me.

Comment: That's not my repo (nor have I ever used deepdetect), but it was just one click away from the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the failing lines are:

```
find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_search_module(Eigen3 REQUIRED eigen3)
```

I do not know if it used to work or why they did it like this but I would give the solution described [here on so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249140/find-package-eigen3-for-cmake#12258855) a try:

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ( "$ENV{EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}" )
```

or

```
SET( EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR "$ENV{EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}" )
IF( NOT EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR )
    MESSAGE( FATAL_ERROR "Please point the environment variable EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR to the include directory of your Eigen3 installation.")
ENDIF()
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ( "${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}" )
```

Comment: Thanks very much. It worked. But wont they update tit into their repo?

Comment: I have no idea what they will do, I did not even know of this project when I saw your question :) . A patch could be sent to the project and they could decide whether they want to change it or not. Even though I do not undestand why they did it like they this, I think that the solution I sent you is simpler and more failproof.

Comment: I just came across this on Eigen3 doc:

[Using Eigen in CMake Projects](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCMakeGuide.html).

edit: btw, if you find this useful, please upvote me :)