# CMake find eigen incorrect results

Tags: c++, cmake, eigen

I am trying to compile a code snippet with `Eigen` using CMake, but CMake seems to have trouble finding the correct path, even if the source code is there.

This is my `CMakeLists.txt` file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14.2)
project(test)

# set default build type
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
endif()


find_package(OpenCV 3 REQUIRED)
find_package (Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)

include_directories(
        include
        ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}
)


add_executable(playground playground.cpp)
target_link_libraries(playground ${OpenCV_LIBS} Eigen3::Eigen)
```

This is how I import headers in `playground.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <math.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <Eigen>
```

My `Eigen` is installed under `/usr/include/eigen3`, here is the directory structure:

```
yuqiong@yuqiong-G7-7588:/usr/include/eigen3$ ls
Eigen  signature_of_eigen3_matrix_library  unsupported
```

So the correct path to Eigen library is `/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen`.

However, when I run `cmake ..` and then `make` for the aforementioned `CMakeLists.txt` file, with the `-LH` flag, CMake complains it can't find `Eigen`. This is the path it thinks where `Eigen` is:

```
yuqiong@yuqiong-G7-7588:/media/yuqiong/DATA/vignetting/catkin_ws/src/vig2/src/build$ cmake -LH ..
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /media/yuqiong/DATA/vignetting/catkin_ws/src/vig2/src/build
-- Cache values
// Choose the type of build, options are: None Debug Release RelWithDebInfo MinSizeRel ...
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=

// Install path prefix, prepended onto install directories.
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/local

// The directory containing a CMake configuration file for Eigen3.
Eigen3_DIR:PATH=/usr/local/share/eigen3/cmake

// The directory containing a CMake configuration file for OpenCV.
OpenCV_DIR:PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/OpenCV-3.3.1-dev
```

This is the structure of the folder where it think Eigen is:

```
yuqiong@yuqiong-G7-7588:/usr/local/share/eigen3$ tree
.
└── cmake
    ├── Eigen3Config.cmake
    ├── Eigen3ConfigVersion.cmake
    ├── Eigen3Targets.cmake
    └── UseEigen3.cmake
```

I am confused why CMake has such behavior? How can I let it find the correct path of `Eigen` in this case?

All this environment set-ups are so tricky to get it right...

Comment: Are you sure `#include <Eigen>` even refers to an actual file? Maybe try `#include <Eigen/Dense>` instead?

Comment: @lubgr I'm going to say something stupid, but do we need to refer to an actual file when doing `#include`? For some libaries we just use `#include <string>`>

Comment: @lubgr also I just deleted the path I thought was wrong --- the path full of `cmake` files. Now CMake can't find anything. I'll re-download `Eigen` and try your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Not a stupid question. You can only `#include` files, not directories.

Comment: @yuqli string is an actual file with that name, located with the rest of the c++ standard library. On ubuntu it's commonly under /usr/include/c++ subdirectories. Not much magic to preprocessing, just textual substitutions..

Comment: There is no problem with CMake. You have Eigen **include directory** `/usr/include`, where it have installed the header files. Note, include directory doesn't have `eigen3` component at the end. So you need to use appropriate `#include` statements. As for `Eigen3_DIR` variable in the cache (equal to `/usr/local/share/eigen3/cmake`), it denotes the directory with **configuration files**. It is not a problem that this directory differs from the include directory: these directories are used for different purposes.(However, I find it strange that one directory contains `share` but another doesn't)

Comment: Oh, `but CMake seems to have trouble finding the correct path, even if the **source** code is there.` - Have you just placed Eigen **source files** under `/usr/include/eigen3`?  Because this is not an **installation**, it has no `Eigen3Config.cmake` file which helps `find_package` to locate it. Instead, you need to get `FindEigen3.cmake` script somewhere, and hint it about this directory (e.g. with `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH` variable). But it is simpler to **install** Eigen (with `cmake`, `make`, `make install`), so `find_package` will be able to find it automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the comments above. I think the issue might be the `Eigen` team changed their directory structure somehow between different versions, and the old include path does not work anymore.

The solution for me was to change `#include <Eigen/Dense>` to `#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>`. After that `g++` and `CMake` can find the path.

I did install `Eigen` following [this official doc](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCMakeGuide.html), which was why I was surprised the installation is still problematic.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491067/eigen-installation-seemed-to-work-but-i-still-cant-make-eigen-work) answer solved my problem.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249140/find-package-eigen3-for-cmake) answer also solves the problem.

On another note, my CMake file was a bit messed up, with both `include_directories` and `target_link_libraries`.