# Cannot find header files using Makefile generated by CMake

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, eigen

my cmake file

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.11)
project (Transformation)

find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR)

add_executable (Transformation main.cpp)
```

After I run `make`

```sh
/Users/.../main.cpp:2:9: fatal error: 'eigen3/Eigen/Core' file not found
#include<eigen3/Eigen/Core>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Transformation.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Transformation.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

OS: MacOS 11.2
cmake version: 3.9.16
make version: 3.81

Comment: Similar question here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249140/find-package-eigen3-for-cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249140/find-package-eigen3-for-cmake)

Comment: Just to make sure the path is correct, can you print it `message(STATUS "Eigen3 path: ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}")` ? Otherwise, looks like dupe of question in another comment.

Comment: First, you're not expanding `${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}` like you should be. Second, you should not use `include_directories`. Use `target_include_directories` instead.

Comment: Also, you should not set the minimum CMake version below what you're actually using to test your build. CMake 2.8.11 is nearly 10 years old at this point. Upgrade!

Comment: Alex is correct. It should be `include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})` instead of `include_directories(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR)`

Comment: In your cpp file you should write `#include<Eigen/Core>` (remove the leading `eigen3/`)

Comment: Tnanks for reply.